# .htaccess 301 redirect to two different sites

Tags: .htaccess, http-status-code-301

Have a site source.com that is getting closed, so we would like to 301 redirect it to two other sites target1.com and target2.com.

Some specific urls on source.com must be 301 redirected to target1.com, including some wildcard urls like source.com/p/*

Other specific urls on source.com must be 301 redirected to target2.com, including some wildcard urls like source.com/q/*

Finally, all the urls that aren't covered by the lists/wildcards above must be redirected to the frontpage of target1.com

Is that possible to do via .htaccess?

Thanks!

Comment: please share your old .htaccess code!

Comment: We are going to delete everything on source.com, so the .htaccess file will be completely blank to begin with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use these rules in your site root .htaccess of `source.com`:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?source\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^p(/.*)?$ http://target1.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NC,R=301,NE]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?source\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^q(/.*)?$ http://target2.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NC,R=301,NE]
```

Even if you delete all content on `source.com`, you must keep the domain alive to make this redirection work.

Comment: Looks good. What if I need to redirect a specific source url to a specific target url (that isn't covered by the wildcards)

Comment: In that case keep specific redirect rules **above those generic rules**

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help.